# Error with opencv when importing joystick.h with types.hpp

Tags: c++, opencv, enums, controller, joystick

I am trying to read the data from an Xbox One controller via Bluetooth on my computer running Ubuntu 20.

The problem appears at the time of compilation, I have the impression that it appears randomly sometimes without any modification on my part of the main code and CMakeLists. Maybe a problem with updates?

```
                 from /usr/include/linux/joystick.h:28,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/include/00_communication.h:23,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/src/00_communication.cpp:1:
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/viz/types.hpp:286:27: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
  286 |             enum Action { KEY_UP = 0, KEY_DOWN = 1};
      |                           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/viz/types.hpp:286:27: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/viz.hpp:49,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:104,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/include/00_function.h:20,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/include/00_communication.h:25,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/src/00_communication.cpp:1:
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/viz/types.hpp:286:25: note: to match this ‘{’
  286 |             enum Action { KEY_UP = 0, KEY_DOWN = 1};
      |                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/linux/input.h:18,
                 from /usr/include/linux/joystick.h:28,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/include/00_communication.h:23,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/src/00_communication.cpp:1:
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/viz/types.hpp:286:27: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
  286 |             enum Action { KEY_UP = 0, KEY_DOWN = 1};
      |                           ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/viz.hpp:49,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:104,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/include/00_function.h:20,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/include/00_communication.h:25,
                 from /home/mon20/Dev/HIVE_ROBOT_SOFTWARE/src/00_communication.cpp:1:
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/viz/types.hpp:295:26: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
  295 |             KeyboardEvent(Action action, const String& symbol, unsigned char code, int modifiers);
      |                          ^
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/viz/types.hpp:297:13: error: ‘Action’ does not name a type
  297 |             Action action;
      |             ^~~~~~
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/viz/types.hpp:331:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
  331 | } /* namespace cv */
```

I tried to modify the Action enum by adding 'class' before it, but it did not work.

Comment: if you built opencv yourself, rebuild with viz module disabled.